# Get 404 when running flask restplus app on amazon ec2

Tags: python-2.7, flask, amazon-ec2, flask-restful, flask-restplus

Okay I have done my research and tried and tested the following

[Related Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50377752/why-do-i-get-404-when-running-flask-app-on-0-0-0-0)

However, none of the solution provided there work and I don't understand why does removing constant will work? It's basically the same thing.

Here is my code,

```
import logging.config

import os, settings
from flask import Flask, Blueprint
from restplus.api.model.endpoints.servemodel import ns as modelserve
from restplus.api.apiInit import api

app = Flask(__name__)
# BASE_DIR=os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))
# logging.config.fileConfig(os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'utils', 'logger.conf'))
# log = logging.getLogger(__name__)

def configure_app(flask_app):
    flask_app.config['SERVER_NAME'] = settings.FLASK_SERVER_NAME
    flask_app.config['SWAGGER_UI_DOC_EXPANSION'] = settings.RESTPLUS_SWAGGER_UI_DOC_EXPANSION
    flask_app.config['RESTPLUS_VALIDATE'] = settings.RESTPLUS_VALIDATE
    flask_app.config['RESTPLUS_MASK_SWAGGER'] = settings.RESTPLUS_MASK_SWAGGER
    flask_app.config['ERROR_404_HELP'] = settings.RESTPLUS_ERROR_404_HELP

def initialize_app(flask_app):
    configure_app(flask_app)
    blueprint = Blueprint('api', __name__)
    api.init_app(blueprint)
    api.add_namespace(modelserve)
    flask_app.register_blueprint(blueprint)


def main():
    initialize_app(app)
    # log.info('>>>>> Starting development server at http://{}/api/ <<<<<'.format(app.config['SERVER_NAME']))
    app.run(debug=settings.FLASK_DEBUG)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Now if you suggest that in Blueprint I set a '/api' path, I have tried it too with no success. The modelserve namespace is just a namespace at / and /recognize for function purpose.

I want my swagger UI to run at 0.0.0.0:5000. The variable settings.FLASK_SERVER_NAME is set to exactly that. And all the console says is that 404 with no explanation what so ever.

I have also tried printing app.url_map and seen that all routes of the app are registered where they should have been registered.

```
    Map([<Rule '/swagger.json' (HEAD, OPTIONS, GET) -> api.specs>,
 <Rule '/recognize/' (POST, OPTIONS) -> api.recognize_hand_written_digit_recognizer>,
 <Rule '/recognize/' (POST, OPTIONS) -> api.recognize_hand_written_digit_recognizer_2>,
 <Rule '/' (HEAD, OPTIONS, GET) -> api.doc>,
 <Rule '/' (HEAD, OPTIONS, GET) -> api.root>,
 <Rule '/swaggerui/<filename>' (HEAD, OPTIONS, GET) -> restplus_doc.static>,
 <Rule '/static/<filename>' (HEAD, OPTIONS, GET) -> static>])
```

But still swagger ui won't work. I am not sure what the problem is and neither does setting debug=True helping me. What can be done here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Figured it out.

When working with Flask-RESTPlus on amazon ec2, put the ip address of the server as the host. So for example, if the ip of the server is ec2-10-221-200-56.us-west-2.compute.amazonaws.com then set it as the host. So the final settings.FLASK_SERVER_NAME="http://ec2-10-221-200-56.us-west-2.compute.amazonaws.com:5000".

This should make your swagger UI and other parts of application work fine!